# Calling SQL function from power Query

Tags: sql, function, powerquery

Guys!

To make calculations ran faster I'm trying to move the logic from PQ calculations to MS SQL on virtual machine, definig functions and using them in T-SQL queries.

Yet pasting code of the working query into PowerQuery, I'm retrieving an error exactly on the launch of my function:
http://shot.qip.ru/00Qqzx-3Vmk2GJhf/

in the SQL itself my function works as it should:
http://shot.qip.ru/00Qqzx-6Vmk2GJhg/

Do you know what can be the reason for this and if there is some workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Answer (score 0):

I've came across the issue.
I had two connections to this datasource, one of them with lower credentials that were required.
So what helped:

1. leaving only one connection in PQ connections manager:
   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Data-source-settings-Power-Query-9f24a631-f7eb-4729-88dd-6a4921380ca9#__toc354511926
2. modifying credentials to the required ones
3. Clearing the PQ cahe.

Now PQ works good (checked on calling SQL Stored Procedure)